# Pointer to a character constant

Tags: c

Sorry for being such a dumb here. Can't sort this out for myself.

In a header file there is a Macro like this.

```
#define kOID  "1.3.6.1.4.1.1.1.2.4.0"
```

How to declare and initialize a char pointer to this data without creating a copy of this string?

Comment: char* const p = kOID;

Comment: Will this create any copy of the string in the memory?

Comment: Yes, in a read-only section of your program. And since you cannot change this string, you don't need more than one copy of it.

Comment: @barakmanos:  The comments section is not the place for *answers*; you have missed an opportunity get credit for answering this.  But with respect to creating a copy the answer to NeonGlow's question is "no" - there is only one instance of the string, the macro definition does not instantiate the string in memory.  I am being somewhat pedantic, since you are obviously aware of that, but you may have confused NeonGlow who I believe is asking whether the data is duplicated.  Semantically, there is one *instance* not one *copy* - that would imply two instances - the original and the copy).

Comment: @Clifford: Thanks. I did not imply anywhere that more than a single copy is created. Obviously, a copy is created only when you instantiate a string (and not when you `#define` one). In any case, I merely stated that since OP cannot change the contents of this string when declaring a `char*` variable to point to it, there is no need for more than one copy.

Comment: @barakmanos:  As I said I was being somewhat pedantic.  A single instance *is not* a copy - its the original.

Comment: @Clifford : My main concern is memory usage since I am going to use such a large number of #defines and the code is for an embedded target with limited memory. Just wanted to make sure the pointer declaration and assignments won't result in any anonymous or non-anonymous data copying.

Comment: @NeonGlow:  Macros in them selves do not generate code, code is generated only at point of use. Your linker can create a map file giving a detailed report of memory usage and allocation.

Comment: @NeonGlow: Added an update for memory-usage considerations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Assuming that you're not planning to change the contents of this string, you can simply use:**

```
char* p = kOID;
```

The string will reside in a read-only section of the program, so any attempt to change its contents will result with a memory access violation during runtime. So for your own safety, you should generally use:

```
const char* p = kOID;
```

Thus, any attempt to change the contents of the string pointed by `p` will lead to a compile-time error instead of a runtime error. The former is typically much easier to track-down and fix than the latter.

**To summarize the `const` issue, here are the options that you can use:**

```
      char*       p = kOID;
      char* const p = kOID; // compilation error if you change the pointer
const char*       p = kOID; // compilation error if you change the pointed data
const char* const p = kOID; // compilation error if you change either one of them
```

**UPDATE - Memory Usage Considerations:**

Please note that every such declaration may result with an additional memory usage, adding up to the length of the string plus one character, plus 4 or 8 bytes for the pointer (depending on your system). Now, the pointer is perhaps less of an issue, but the string itself might yield an extensive memory usage if you instantiate it in several places in the code. So if you're planning to use the string in various places within your program, then you should probably declare it globally in one place.

In addition, please note that the string may reside either in the code-section of the program or in the data-section of the program. Depending on your memory partitions, you may prefer having it in one place over the other.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I wanted to know. I think my question was not clear and made some confusion. Apart from the RAM usage I think this will result in an increase in executable size also since the pre-processor will replace kOid with actual string.

Comment: @NeonGlow: You're welcome (see additional paragraph at the bottom of the answer).

Comment: I tried writing a simple program and printed the character pointers. Different pointers are all pointing to the same location means possibly there is only one copy of data. The contents of the updated paragraph might be incorrect. Please consider revisiting.

Comment: @NeonGlow: Have you declared `char* p = kOID` inside different functions in your code? Perhaps your compiler is capable of identifying this and performing an optimization.

Comment: @NeonGlow: After trying that, the compiler indeed creates a single instance for this string (**even** without using the macro). Very interesting; I wonder how it is capable of identifying this case. I will remove the paragraph stating that it instantiate different copies of that string.

Comment: In my sample program all pointers were declared in the same function. Honestly, I am confused. :) May be we could try after turning off all the optimizations.

Comment: @NeonGlow: I have checked this issue, and the compiler may or may not choose to use the same constant string (i.e., instantiate it only once). It probably did so in your case. I'm pretty sure that if you have the same string over **several different files**, then it will not be able to do so. Hence, the *Memory Usage Considerations* paragraph in my answer (now removed) was generally correct.

Comment: @NeonGlow: Thank you for putting it back into the answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Preprocessor macros are nothing but a textual substitution. Thus if you write

```
  const char *pointer = kOID;
```

the preprocessor will substitute the text with

```
  const char *pointer = "1.3.6.1.4.1.1.1.2.4.0";
```

One thing to bear in mind is that the `const` specifier is necessary since once the textual substitution is made, the memory will be allocated on read-only segments.

Also be careful to have the macro visible at the point where you'd like to declare that pointer.

Comment: Literals are constants by default.

Comment: The `const` is necessary only for your own safety (will generate a compile-time error instead of a runtime error if you attempt to change the contents of the string). The string will reside in the read-only section of the program in any case (with or without the `const`).

Comment: In this case I hope we are just substituting the entire text. So this will result in increase in code size. What about the RAM usage? Will two copies of the same string be present RAM? If we are declaring such pointer variables more than once, will the data be replicated more than once?

Comment: kOID just gets replaced with the "1.3.6..". There will be one string present, in read-only memory, pointed at by `pointer`. If you declare more than one pointer to it, I'm not sure whether the compiler would make them point at the same thing, but I assume so, seeing as it is read-only.

Comment: @SamvanKampen : Many Thanks :). Was thinking this is just a dumb text replacement at the pre-processing stage which will result in increase in code size.

Comment: @NeonGlow I just tested using gdb: it referred to the same memory address.

Comment: @SamvanKampen : Really appreciate the effort. Failed to think about checking this using gdb.

Comment: @NeonGlow: Be aware that combining of duplicate string constants is a feature of *some* linkers and is by no means guaranteed by the language definition.  Also it is usually possible to enable/disable that feature via command line options.

Answer (score 1):

include the header file first.

```
#include <header.h>
```

Add the defined constant

```
char * s = kOID;
```

This will compile the program fine. However as `kOID` is a string literal it'll be saved on read only memory of your program. So if you modify the `s` it'll cause `Segmentation fault`. The get around is to make `s` constant.

```
const char * s = kOID;
```

Now if you compile the program compiler will check any assignment on `s` and notice accordingly.

```
a.c: In function ‘main’:
a.c:10:5: error: assignment of read-only location ‘*s’
```

So you'll be safe.

Comment: I'd make that a `const` pointer, just to make clear that it can't be edited.

Comment: AFAIK literals are constants by default

Comment: As @barakmanos said, it is just for your own safety; so you'll get a compile-time error.

Comment: `const` doesn't "make anything constant" at all. It just assures the compiler you are not intending to modify it (treat it as read only). A _string constant_ is something else: a literal string that resides in read only memory.

Answer (score 0):

To add to what has been said by others, also you can initialize your array this way:

```
const char some_string[] = kOID;
```

This is similar to `const char *const some_string = kOID;`. Possibly, it may lead to additional memory allocation but this depends on compiler.